# How compare the size of two arrays in mongo?

Tags: mongodb

I have two fields with separate arrays that have comparable data in them.

The first has a Name, and an ID. The second has a nickname.

I want to make sure that the count of the two are the same. If they are not the same, I want to know the mongoID of that document.

How would I do this?

Comment: Please show your effort what you have done. Until then we cannot help you.

Comment: Just add a field that tracks it. Super reliable and very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

With [MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) it would be possible. If your document looks like:

```
document: { array1: [ a, b], array2: [c] }
```

You could write `map` and `reduce` functions like:

```
map = function(){ 
   if(this.array1.length!=this.array2.length)
     emit(this_id,1);
}

reduce = function(key,values){ return key;}
```

For instance, to get the results inline:

```
db.foo.mapReduce(map,reduce,{out:{inline:1}}).results
```

Comment: I would rather eval it than fire up the mr engine tbh

Comment: This is a perfect answer.